# How to add an empty entity at runtime in C# MVC/Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a class books that contains a list of readers. I would to add as many reader entity as I need to but I don't know how/what I am supposed to do.

In the front-end, I have an add button that create an empty line with firstname/lastname. Do I need to request a empty user model through an ajax call everytime I want to add a line or is there a way to stack them up and save them on the submit ?

I came accross http://knockoutmvc.com/CartEditor but I have read some articles that says 'don't use it'. So what is the best way to add a line without refreshing the whole page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend using Knockoutmvc, because you can't create your own controller, and Knockoutmvc's controller is sealed. Just use plain knockout.js. Here is how add an entity to collection with JavaScript.

Code in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ...

    var newItemJsonString = "@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyItemViewModel())))";

    // start knockout

    MyEntity.Init(data, newItemJsonString, '@ViewBag.PostbackUrl');
</script>
```

It has several function calls:

- JavaScriptStringEncode to sanitize javascript string
- SerializeObject to convert your C# view model to javascript representation

The result page will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ...    

    var newItemJsonString = "{\"Title\":null,\"OwnerComment\":null,\"IsTextareaVisible\":false}";

    // start knockout

    MyEntity.Init(data, newItemJsonString, '/my-url');
</script>
```

Then you can use this JSON string in your model on client side to create an object:

```
    // parse a string to create new object

    var newObject = JSON.parse(self.newItemJsonString);

    // then make knockout mapping based on newly created object

    var newModelItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(newObject);

    // then push it to our model

    model.Items.push(newModelItem);
```

Your model may vary. I have collection of Items in my model and this approach works for me very well. Note that my MyItemViewModel is just an item inside of another view model. My full viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    // ... other properties...
    public List<MyItemViewModel>   Items                { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: Good answer. However, I'd simplify the JSON encode of the model to just: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new ItemViewModel()))`. There's no need to encode as a string and then decode the JSON object from a string.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, good comment. I don't remember why I decided to encode that. And it seems like it can be simplified!

Comment: Maybe it's because I can't predict and don't want to be dependent on the type of quotes (double or single) generated by third-party API (I use Newtonsoft.Json). And I needed a string, to be able to create new object with JSON.parse, which accept string only as a parameter.

Comment: The type of quote doesn't matter because the result is a JSON object defined straight in your JavaScript code. It's just like any other JS object. To be able to create a new object you pass it to `ko.mapping.fromJS` as-is, no need to involve `JSON.parse`.